# Restrict SSH Access to Specific IP for User

Tags: ssh, security

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file has a line like:

```
AllowUsers jim@11.22.33.456
```

If I want to allow `jim` to use another IP addresses, how do I specify it?

Does it take the form of a comma separated list? Or, do add a similar line like

```
AllowUsers jim@new-ip-address
```

?

Comment: The manapage is pretty clear on this: "This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would do

```
AllowUsers jim@11.22.33.56 jim@141.212.133.36
```

OR

```
AllowUsers jim@11.22.33.*
```

should work, that is if you are internal and he has a dynamic ip.

Comment: I have similar Error. I want `root` to login to any IP, I want `user1` to login from specific ip for example `1.2.3.4` and I want all other users to login from any IP. How do I do this?

Comment: @AdarshSojitra you don't want a remote access for the user `root`.