# Increase security for ssh login via public / private key: use port forwarding in router or in server?

Tags: ssh, router, port-forwarding

I want to access my Ubuntu server from the internet via SSH storing the client's public key on that server.

In order to increase security I want to use a different port than 22 to reduce risk of a break in into my server (as script kids have to guess that port number).

**Is it better to define the port forwarding in the router (like depicted below) or at the server (as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/264048)?**

[image]

Comment: Either way works, but you won't stop SSH activity on the odd port, most service scanners can *all* ports and they'll come knocking anyways on port 22.  Only true way to secure your server from that is to use a "denial of trust" approach and only allow SSH from IPs you trust.

Comment: Either is fine in my opinion. I don't think you will get any definite answer to this. Changing the default port just reduces the number of remote login attempts in the system log.

Comment: I might not understand the question correctly, but I think you need both. You need to port forward on the router, and then you also need the server to be listening on that port.

Comment: @DougSmythies you can have the router listen to say port 220022 and set it to forward it to port 22 of the IP 192.168.1.200. This way you don't have to edit the `sshd_config`.

Comment: Agreed. There is no option but to do port forwarding at the router. The question is to forward to port 22 internally and do nothing at the server OR forward to port 3074 and also modify the server config. In my opinion, it makes no difference on the internal network.

Comment: I think what @ThomasWard is saying is use [something like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262937/restrict-ssh-access-to-specific-ip-for-user). This may work if you have a handful of remote locations (say office and sister's place) to login from. This won't work if you travel a lot and want to login from all the hotel's Internet connection.

Comment: You should also use https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man8/sshguard.8.html

Comment: `sshguard` and `fail2ban` are good choices for denial of repeat login attempts that fail.  I strongly recommend using one of those options for adding protection to your SSH server.

Comment: @user68186 that approach can work well if you have a VPN server. I allow access to the remote host only from the VPN server, then I can connect to that from anywhere and then access the remote host.

Comment: @OrganicMarble This is a good point. I will add it to my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @user68186 please, feel free!

Comment: Feel free to accept one of the answers as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will indicate your problem is solved and help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It (mostly) does not matter

If you just want to reduce the number of login attempts in the server's system log, either approach is fine.

To be specific here are the two approaches:

1. You can have the router listen to say port 220022 and set it to forward it to port 22 of the IP 192.168.1.200. This way you don't have to edit the `sshd_config` in the server.
2. You can have the router listen to say port 220022 and set it to forward it to port 220022 of the IP 192.168.1.200. This way you have to edit the `sshd_config` in the server so that it does not listen to the default port 22 and listens to the port you selected.

## What about local threats?

If you are worried about someone at your home breaking into your server or someone in a black van parking outside your home and then breaking into your home WiFi network, and then try to break into your server. Then just changing the default port probably won't save you.

## Other measures

As pointed out by Thomas Ward in the comments, restricting ssh access to only a few external IP address is a better security measure. See [Restrict SSH Access to Specific IP for User](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262937/restrict-ssh-access-to-specific-ip-for-user) for how to do that.

This works if you have a handful of remote locations (say office and sister's place) to login from. It is different if you travel a lot and want to login from all the hotel's Internet.

### VPN to solve the "hotel" problem

You will need a VPN service, either provided by your employer or a consumer-grade paid VPN. Then you can add the VPN server's IP address (or a range of IP addresses) to the list of allowed IP addresses. When on the road (in a hotel) connect to the VPN first and then connect to your ssh server.

### Stop the Brute Force

There are various tools to stop repeated unsuccessful attempts (brute force) to ssh. `fail2ban` and `sshguard` are both highly regarded.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> In order to increase security I want to use a different port than 22 to reduce risk of a break in into my server (as script kids have to guess that port number).

It doesn't work like that. An attacker that doesn't know how to run `nmap` won't launch anything novel against you. They may attempt brute force attacks, which you can trivially defend against with good passwords, rate restriction (e.g. fail2ban or sshguard), or simply disallow password logins.

So don't bother. Any attacker that is an actual threat won't be fooled. Remember that the [entire internet](https://www.shodan.io/) is regularly portscanned.